# How Can I show this determinant positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> **Question:-** Suppose that $a_{1}>a_{2}>a_{3}$ and $r_{1}>r_{2}>r_{3}$ are positive real numbers. Prove that the determinant

$A=\begin{vmatrix}a_{1}^{r_{1}} & a_{1}^{r_{2}} & a_{1}^{r_{3}} \\  
a_{2}^{r_{1}} & a_{2}^{r_{2}} & a_{2}^{r_{3}} \\ a_{3}^{r_{1}} &   a_{3}^{r_{2}} & a_{3}^{r_{3}}  \end{vmatrix}$

is positive.

On calculating this determinant we get

$a_{1}^{r_{1}}a_{2}^{r_{2}}a_{3}^{r_{3}}-a_{1}^{r_{1}}a_{3}^{r_{2}}a_{2}^{r_{3}}-a_{1}^{r_{2}}a_{2}^{r_{1}}a_{3}^{r_{3}}+a_{2}^{r_{3}}a_{3}^{r_{1}}a_{1}^{r_{2}}-a_{1}^{r_{3}}a_{2}^{r_{1}}a_{3}^{r_{2}}+a_{1}^{r_{3}}a_{2}^{r_{2}}a_{3}^{r_{1}}$

This method doesn't give any hope of proving determinant positive.

As $Det(A)=\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}$

where, $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\lambda_{3}$ are eigenvalues of $A$

Since eigenvalues are roots of characteristic equation

$p(\lambda)=Det(A-\lambda I)=0$

Products of roots of equation $Ax^{3}+Bx^{2}+Cx+D$ is $\frac{-D}{A}$

$p(\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix}a_{1}^{r_{1}}-\lambda & a_{1}^{r_{2}} & a_{1}^{r_{3}} \\  
a_{2}^{r_{1}} & a_{2}^{r_{2}}-\lambda & a_{2}^{r_{3}} \\ a_{3}^{r_{1}} &   a_{3}^{r_{2}} & a_{3}^{r_{3}}-\lambda  \end{vmatrix}=0$

Since Constant terms $(D)$ in this Cubic equation occur with alternating $+,-$ sign I don't think that this method will either help.

So How can I prove this determinant positive?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3639531.